# Why does expr match outputs different things when the pattern (not) contains a parenthesized group?

Tags: regex, linux, bash, pattern-matching

Why does

```
$ echo `expr match abcdef 'abc'`
```

give number of characters matched, which is 3, but

```
$ echo `expr match abcdef '\(abc\)'`
```

gives the characters matched , which is abc ?

I understand regex matching is in play here, but cannot understand how having a parenthesized sub expression is making this difference here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That has nothing to do with regular expressions. It is only a difference how the command "expr" works. The first one returns the length of the matching substring and the second one returns the matching substring itself.

There is a very good summary: [TLDP refcard](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/refcards.html). You find a summary of combinations how expr can be used.

Answer (score 7):

This is from the man page of expr :

`Pattern matches return the string matched between \( and \) or null; if \( and \) are not used, they return the number of characters matched or 0.`

[Man page.](http://linux.die.net/man/1/expr)

Comment: Agreed, the man page says this. But why does it behave like this ? What is the root cause for this behavior ? Can we explain this in terms of regex usage ?

Comment: @abc : This is how expr was programed to work. There is nothing more to it.